# Extjs 4.2 : How to set button position dynamically in grid rowediting with multiline row (wrapping column/row)?

Tags: extjs4.2

I have this case, already try many way but not find solution.

I make a grid with wrapping column (rendering column with style white-space:normal;) and with rowediting plugin.
So when value in the column is quite long, the row's height will be longer than usual.
And when edit the row (edit mode), the vertical alignment of column value and column editor will be in the middle row, but the button (Save - Cancel) position not follow to bottom of the edited row.
So the button will be covering certain column value or column editor (as in captured image).

[image: captured image case]

So I try two alternative ways :

1. try to set column value/editor vertical alignment when in edit mode to top, but can not found how to make it done
2. try to set button position at bottom row follow the row height (i think it is the right/proper way), and also can not found how to make it done.

Anybody have solution for this case?

Thank you.